# Prove $L = F(β)$, where $β^p = F$ via Hilbert's Theorem 90

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field that contains a primitive $p$-th root of unity, where $p$ is a prime. I wish to prove that if $L$ is Galois over $F$ and $[L : F] = p$, then $L = F(β)$, where $β^p = F$. Does anyone know of a proof via Hilbert's Theorem 90?

That is, making use of the fact that: Given $Gal(L|F)$ is cyclic of order $n$ and $σ$ is a generator of $G$, suppose $δ_0 = α, δ_1 = ασ(α), δ_2 = ασ(α)σ^2(α), · · · ,δ_{n−1} = ασ(α)· · · σ^{n−1}(α) =$ 'norm' $N(α) = 1$ and $γ ∈ L$ is such that
$β = δ_0γ + δ_1σ(γ) + · · · + δ_{n−1}σ
^{n−2}(γ) + σ^{n−1}(γ) ≠ 0$. Then we have $α = βσ(β)^{−1}$

Comment: You wrote $\beta^p = F$: how does that work?  Do you mean $\beta^p \in F$?  Cheers!

Comment: What make you think it is possible ? Personally I don't see the link. H90 just describes the elements of norm $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, perhaps I am mistaken hmm is there a direct way then to prove the proposition?

Comment: Perhaps it is misleading to label the above fact as H90 but this result supposedly can be used to prove the proposition, though yea I am also confused as to how~

Comment: $Gal(L/F)$ is abelian cyclic of prime degree generated by $\sigma$. If you have Hilbert 90 then pick directly $\beta = \zeta_p \sigma^m(\beta)$ so that $\sigma^{lm} (\beta) = \zeta_p^l\beta$ and $\beta^p \in F,\beta \not \in F, L= F(\beta)$ . But the method you mentionned does reprove it in this particular case :  take a primitive element $L = F(\alpha)$ and look at $\beta = \sum_{l=1}^p\zeta_p^{-l} \sigma^l(\alpha)$ then $\sigma(\beta) = \zeta_p\beta,\sigma^l (\beta) = \zeta_p^l\beta$.

Comment: This is basically Kummer theory, and many textbooks cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity in $F$. Then $N_{L/F}(\zeta)=\zeta^p=1$. By Hilbert 90, there is $\alpha\in L^*$ with
$\sigma(\alpha)/\alpha=\zeta$, that
is
$$\sigma(\alpha)=\zeta\alpha.$$
But then
$$\sigma(\alpha^p)=\sigma(\alpha)^p=\zeta^p\alpha^p$$
so that $\alpha^p=a\in F$. But $\sigma(\alpha)\ne\alpha$ so $\alpha\notin F$.
Thus $L=F(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^p\in F$.